# C# Console Window scrolling issue with long text

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have been using the console window in dotnet C# for the longest time .

I never experienced problems on my previous laptop with windows 10, but on my new laptop with windows 11:

I experienced everything from BUFFER swash TEXT overflow, to ARTIFACTS, to SCROLL COPYING problems and more .

I tried to familiarize myself more with the console window:

```
if (reset)
{
    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
    Console.CursorTop = 0;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop);
}
else
{
    Int32 left, top, size;
    left = 16;
    top = 32;
    size = (left * top);
    Int32 bufferSize, windowSize;
    bufferSize = (Console.BufferWidth * Console.BufferHeight);
    windowSize = (Console.WindowWidth * Console.WindowHeight);
    var is_EXCEED_invalid = false;
    is_EXCEED_invalid = is_EXCEED_invalid || (size < 0) is true;
    is_EXCEED_invalid = is_EXCEED_invalid || (left < 0) is true;
    is_EXCEED_invalid = is_EXCEED_invalid || (top < 0) is true;
    var is_EXCEED_buffer = false;
    is_EXCEED_buffer = is_EXCEED_buffer || (size >= bufferSize) is true;
    is_EXCEED_buffer = is_EXCEED_buffer || (left >= Console.BufferWidth) is true;
    is_EXCEED_buffer = is_EXCEED_buffer || (top >= Console.BufferHeight) is true;
    var is_EXCEED_window = false;
    is_EXCEED_window = is_EXCEED_window || (size >= windowSize) is true;
    is_EXCEED_window = is_EXCEED_window || (left >= Console.WindowWidth) is true;
    is_EXCEED_window = is_EXCEED_window || (top >= Console.WindowHeight) is true;
    Boolean isExceedCheck;
    isExceedCheck = false;
    isExceedCheck = isExceedCheck || is_EXCEED_invalid is true;
    isExceedCheck = isExceedCheck || is_EXCEED_buffer is true;
    isExceedCheck = isExceedCheck || is_EXCEED_window is true;

    if (isExceedCheck)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.CursorLeft = 16;
        Console.CursorTop = 40;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop);
    }
    Console.BackgroundColor = ImmutableOneFirst.BackgroundColor;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ImmutableOneFirst.ForegroundColor;
}
if (hide)
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;
}
else
{
    Console.CursorVisible = true;
}
if (clear is true)
{
    Console.Clear();
}
else
    "false".ToString();
```

In the process of me familiarizing myself with the console window and in my endless discussions with chat gpt, I realized the console windows is getting old and nobody is replacing it, one example of that is on this specific laptop, I cannot set the window position to ANY value including its OWN CURRENT value .

With all this in mind I wrote the following code to try and detect and validate various console overflows, then I did the same for the actual LARGE CONTENTS STRING I am displaying earlier .

What the console says is that NO OVERFLOW occurs since both the BUFFER SIZE and the WINDOW SIZE are bigger than the STRING CONTENT SIZE .

But the problem is the string is so large, that when I launch the console, I am automatically scrolled to the bottom of the string, and when I try to scroll up, the upper part gets copied and pasted whole bunch of times leading to very poor user experience .

How do I resolve that ?

I tried detecting the overflow and take actions in regards to it, turns out there was no overflow that can be detected since the numbers did not exceed each other, yet there is an actual visible overflow and no action in regards to resizing the buffer helps significantly

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? The console is great for small tools, or things that need little to no user interaction. But if you are running into buffer limits you might be using the wrong tool.

Comment: Usually overflow do not happen on small character pages, but when the page is so big that it requires a scroll, overflow takes place, I am trying to create a series of intertwined small executables that each contribute to the overall IO product, I have done 3 of them already because their pages did not require scroll at all, but this one is big and it does

Comment: If your components are mainly intended to communicate with each other, than you should probably consider better ways of doing IPC. Like some sort of message queue/buss. Or at least leverage the object orientation of PowerShell.

Comment: I do not know how to change my current console interface to a more modern one, and no the primary focus of these applications is not just to communicate with each other but also to be fired from a centralized executable with a bunch of escaping user-friendly mechanisms

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Windows Console and Terminal Ecosystem Roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ecosystem-roadmap) and [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).